# Neo4j super slow edge insert

Tags: java, neo4j

Such a simple thing but... I am following https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/create/#create-create-a-relationship-between-two-nodes but On Neo4j, the following Cypher query takes more than 120 seconds:

```
MATCH (from:PubmedDocumentNode), (to:PubmedAuthorNode) 
WHERE from.PMID = 26408320 
AND to.Author_Name = "Bando|Mika|M|" 
CREATE (from)-[:AUTHOR {labels:[],label:[3.0],Id:0}]->(to)
```

There are also indexes:

```
Indexes 
 ON :PubmedAuthorNode(Author_Name) ONLINE 
 ON :PubmedDocumentNode(PMID) ONLINE 

No constraints
```

so.. why??

EDIT: The same query without the create part runs in no time.

Comment: What are EXPLAIN and PROFILE reporting ?

You could do 
MATCH (from:PubmedDocumentNode {from.PMID: 26408320})
MATCH (to:PubmedAuthorNode {Author_Name = "Bando|Mika|M|"}) 
CREATE ....

Else is machine under heavy charge ?

Comment: Explain profiles for my query and yours are the same. i've killed profile query after 10 minutes. Machine is under NO load.

Comment: @Jerome_B see my edit

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? And can you remove the CREATE and instead return `count(*)` so we can know how many result rows you're dealing with?

Comment: Already done. Without count the query returns immediately with the two nodes.

Comment: I suggest removing the creation of empty 'labels' array property .
This can be done in a second query (EDIT: I thought that was for all relations).
What is label ? an array of float ? try toFloat("3.0") just to see what is puzzling the parser.

If you can remove all AUTHOR relation from your base, try to create the AUTHOR rel with only one value then two, in order to find what brings the bottleneck

Comment: Can you give the result of this query : MATCH (from:PubmedDocumentNode), (to:PubmedAuthorNode) 
WHERE from.PMID = 26408320 AND to.Author_Name = "Bando|Mika|M|" 
RETURN size((from)-[:AUTHOR]->()), size(()-[:AUTHOR]->(to))

Comment: @logisima 18, 1

Comment: Humm, it's really weird, can you add the `EXPLAIN` of your write query in your post ?